# Usermod -aG vs gpasswd -a as a best practice

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, users, best-practices

I am aware that `usermod -g` is not best practice from many [posts like this](http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2004-September/msg02595.html) however they normally explain the `usermod` should not be used as it changes the primary group of a user. These posts don't seem to take into account the `-aG` switch which just appends the group.

Is this still poor practice or no different than using `gpasswd -a`?

Comment: Did you happen to look at the date of that message?

Comment: Yeah but theres tons like it and someone recently said something along the lines of it to me so I thought best to ask.

Comment: I want to add to your question and put adduser command, ive seen it here https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/50652376_2223011044630296_4695711839483330560_o.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ht=scontent-mad1-1.xx&oh=60b28532969299a730f8f9f63994ca00&oe=5CBF76F5

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They both can do the same, it's just with `usermod` you can do it wrong if you don't pay enough attention.

In [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Users_and_groups#Group_management) from Arch Linux (*it is the same for other distros*), it's explained:

> To add a user to other groups use (additional_groups is a
> comma-separated list):
>
> ```
> # usermod -aG additional_groups username
> ```
>
> > Warning: **If the `-a` option is omitted in the `usermod` command above, the
> > user is removed from all groups not listed in additional_groups** (i.e.
> > the user will be member only of those groups listed in
> > additional_groups).
>
> Alternatively, `gpasswd` may be used. Though the username can only be
> added (or removed) from one group at a time.
>
> ```
> # gpasswd --add username group
> ```